# Find plausible peaks in streamed data

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, noise, real-time

i have got a signal of a streamed source which produces values like in the picture.

I want to get the "real" peaks (blue circles). 
But the noisy peaks (red circles) mess up the peak search.

- The values range from 1-0
- I can't put a threshold for the peaks since the can differ in value by much and noise peaks can occur on high values as well.
- The data is streamed value by value
- the peaks need to be determined as exact as possible
- The detection must be fast since it is used in a real time application

The "real" peaks always have the characteristic to be "smooth". They always look like a peak of a $-x^2$ function. But i have found no way to model that so it is possible to distinguish between a sudden peak of noise and a real peak. [image]

Comment: Something like: Count only the highest peak between two troughs below .7? This could be programmed sequentially by 'resetting' peak detection after each trough and taking max of peaks until the next reset.

Comment: So simple yet so brilliant. Thanks, works like a charm!

Comment: @Luca. I suppose that this question is somehow related to the question : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422954/check-whether-data-forms-a-curve-or-not which was closed. If this question is still topical for you, I have an answer.