# Check whether data forms a curve or not

Tags: regression, time-series, modeling, dataset

I have a set of lists and need to determine if the data of every list forms a curve. The picture below is an example of how the data looks plotted. Humanly it is easy to identify which ones are the desired ones, but i can't figure out a statistical model to identify the correct lists.

'Correct' data-lists: 1,4,5,6,8,10,11,13,16

'Incorrect' data-lists: 2,3,7,9,12,14,15

It is clear that the data i want forms a curve which is similar to a $-x^2$ function.

Since the data can be rather noisy (8,10,11 for example) it does not work very well to fit a 'perfect curve' to determine if the data is correct.

The method should not take too long, since it is used in a streamed environment.

[The data values](https://pastebin.com/XP3EHKU6)
[image: The data plots]

Comment: You are going to have to define 'forms a curve' more precisely for this to be answerable.

Comment: There is arguably curvature in #7, for example.

Comment: A rough estimate can be made by fitting A) a first-order polynomial (straight line) and B) a second-order polynomial (parabola), and then comparing some fit statistic such as RMSE or R-squared to see if the straight line fit is worse that the parabola by some predetermined limit. That will not work in every single case, but should be OK most of the time.